# How to create pdf Template with the dynamic values

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdf-to-html, dynamicpdf

I am stuck in this task from a month ago so my last option is to post my query on stack-overflow.
                 I have to find a PDF Creation tool where i can crate my PDF Template and also i can assign a data source like sql server or any thing else. by which the sql server dynamic data can replace the value of pdf template Tags.' 
I have tried many tools like Foxit and bulzip . But any of the tool does not meets my requirement. I must say I have completely stuck in this Task.
                                                                So Please give me appropriate solution . Immediate response will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/). It's a very simple console utility that creates PDF from HTML. So basically you need to generate HTML markup. You can use some scripting language (PHP, python, etc.) or templating engine, depending on what exactly you want and what tools you are familiar with.

1. Create HTML/CSS markup for your template.
2. Define places where you want to put dynamic data, mark it
       somehow.
3. Create script that will query database for your data and then
4. Either use search&replace in your script to place real data, or
       copy whole HTML as a template using some templating engine (for
       instance, PHP is itself a template engine, so you can basically
       place save template as PHP file where real data is placed where
       needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create pdf in client side, you can try [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

If you are using php for server side, you can try [mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/).